# Using AJAX in a Widget to Sort items

Tags: widgets, jquery

Hi I am trying to use jQuery sortable to sort items in a widget on the admin side.

However I am having trouble getting any data in the JS file when I do `alert(order)`.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

in the php file:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Test widget
*/


add_Action('widgets_init', 'boj_widgetexample_register_widgets');

// register our widget
function boj_widgetexample_register_widgets() {
    register_widget('boj_widgetexample_widget_my_info');
 }



class boj_widgetexample_widget_my_info extends WP_Widget {

        // process the new widget
        function boj_widgetexample_widget_my_info() {
            $widget_opts = array(
                'classname' => 'boj_widgetexample_widget_class',
                'description' => 'Display a user favourite movie and song'
            );
            $this->WP_Widget('boj_widgetexample_widget_my_info', 'My info widget', $widget_ops);
            /* load the widget javascript for the widgets admin screen. */
            add_action( 'load-widgets.php', array(&$this, 'my_widget_admin_script') );

            // function to process ajax order
            add_action('wp_ajax_mywidget_update_order',array(&$this, 'my_widget_save_order') );                 

        }

                    // displaying the widget form in admin
        function form($instance) {
            $defaults = array('title'=>'my info', 'movie'=>'','song'=>'');
            $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults);
            $title = $instance['title'];
            $movie = $instance['movie'];
            $song = $instance['song'];
            ?>
            <ul class="mywidget-list">
            <li class="list_item">Title: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></li>
            <li class="list_item">Movie: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('movie'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($movie); ?>" /></li>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $('.mywidget-list').sortable({
                        items: '.list_item',
                        opacity: 0.6,
                        cursor: 'move',
                        axis: 'y',
                        update: function() {
                            console.log(this);                              
                            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize')+ '&action=mywidget_update_order';
                            alert(order);
                            $.post(ajaxurl, order, function(response){
                            alert(response);
                            //  success maybe alert the user
                            })
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>
        <?php }


        // saving the widget options
        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
            $instance = $old_instance;
            $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title'] );
            $instance['movie'] = strip_tags($new_instance['movie'] );
            $instance['song'] = strip_tags($new_instance['song'] );

            return $instance;
        }

        // output on front end
        function widget($args, $instance) {
            extract($args);

            echo $before_widget;
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title']);
            $movie = empty($instance['movie'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['movie'];

            if ( ! empty($title)) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; }
        }


        /* Push the widget scripts into widget admin page */
        function my_widget_admin_script() {                     
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
            wp_enqueue_script('update-order', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/update-order.js');

        }       

        function my_widget_save_order() {
            echo 'test';

            //print_r($_POST);
            //die();
        }


  }
```

Comment: This seems to have very little to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you are loading will apply the sortable to all elements with the `.mywidget-list` class just after the document has loaded.

Once you drop your widget inside a sidebar, a **new** `.mywidget-list` element is created trough $.ajax, which cannot have your sortable function attached to it, because it's new. If you save the widget, the form HTML gets replaced with $.ajax, so again a new element is created in the DOM.

There are two solutions that I know of:

1. Put your JS inside the form method (inline javascript)
2. Wrap your sortable call within a function that you hook on the [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) event. This means your function will run each time an ajax request completes. You might want to check here if the element already has a sortable attached, to avoid conflicts

Comment: How would the code look like for the 1st option? I'm a bit green on jQuery.

Comment: Exactly what you have posted above, but wrapped between `<script>` and `</script>` tags

Comment: I tried putting the script within the form() function enclosed within `<script>` but it didnt work.

Comment: Does the sorting work? Can you move items around?

Comment: Yes, but the order variable is still not returning correctly, it only alerts '&action=mywidget_update_order'

Comment: you need to have ID attributes on the `LI`s